# Javascript - Find the Position of a Newline Character from a Certain position

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the text below stored in the variable `description`:

```
`This is a code update`

Official Name: 2011 New York City Electrical Code

Code Tile Name:

Reference: https://www.nyc.gov/site/buildings/codes/electrical-code.page

Citation: §27-3024

Doc Title: Local Law 39-2011, Local Law 99-2013, Local Law 39-2015

Source Doc: https://www.nyc.gov/assets/buildings/pdf/ll39of2011_electrical_code.pdf

Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Q0_G3VITpx0iCULtANMHqydAv0ZmvcF/view?usp=share_link

Effective Date: November 19, 2013 


**SCTOMJ**
```

I want to extract the data corresponding to the phrase `Official Name', which is '2011 New York City Electrical Code`.  I used the code below:

```
var official_name = description.search("Official Name:"); 
if(official_name != -1){
    official_name = description.substring(official_name + 14, description.indexOf("Code Tile Name:")).trim();
}
```

The problem with the code above is it depends on the location of the phrase "Code Tile Name:", which should not be because sometimes the arrangement of the information will differ. I want my code to be sequence-independent.

Is there any way to get the first newline character after a certain position?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [look behind assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) to find the line that starts with "Official Name:". The string after the official name should contain all characters except for line breaks.

**Note**: use the multiline flag (`/m`) to make the expression `^Official Name` look for the start of lines, and not the start of the entire text.

```js
const str = `\`This is a code update\`

Official Name: 2011 New York City Electrical Code

Code Tile Name:

Reference: https://www.nyc.gov/site/buildings/codes/electrical-code.page

Citation: §27-3024

Doc Title: Local Law 39-2011, Local Law 99-2013, Local Law 39-2015

Source Doc: https://www.nyc.gov/assets/buildings/pdf/ll39of2011_electrical_code.pdf

Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Q0_G3VITpx0iCULtANMHqydAv0ZmvcF/view?usp=share_link

Effective Date: November 19, 2013 


**SCTOMJ**`

const result = str.match(/(?<=^Official Name:)[^\n\r]+/m)

console.log(result?.[0].trim())
```

Comment: Hey, lookbehind operator is not supported in non-V8 browsers, such as Safari, and Internet Explorer, and this answer is also not working in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a capture group:

```
^Official Name:[ \t]*(.+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Official Name:` Match literally
- `[ \t]*` Match optional spaces or tabs
- `(.+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any character except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKUb7m/1)

```js
const s = `\`This is a code update\`

Official Name: 2011 New York City Electrical Code

Code Tile Name:

Reference: https://www.nyc.gov/site/buildings/codes/electrical-code.page

Citation: §27-3024

Doc Title: Local Law 39-2011, Local Law 99-2013, Local Law 39-2015

Source Doc: https://www.nyc.gov/assets/buildings/pdf/ll39of2011_electrical_code.pdf

Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Q0_G3VITpx0iCULtANMHqydAv0ZmvcF/view?usp=share_link

Effective Date: November 19, 2013 


**SCTOMJ**`

const m = s.match(/^Official Name:[ \t]*(.+)/m)
if (m)
  console.log(m[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

### The `indexOf` method takes two arguments, the *first is the character to search* and the *second is the index at which to start the search*.

```
indexOf(character_to_search, index_to_start_search)
```

**Small feedback-**
Instead of hardcode `14` in your code, you can calculate the length of the "Official Name" word.

Here is the demo-

```js
const description = `\`This is a code update\`

Official Name: 2011 New York City Electrical Code

Code Tile Name:

Reference: https://www.nyc.gov/site/buildings/codes/electrical-code.page

Citation: §27-3024

Doc Title: Local Law 39-2011, Local Law 99-2013, Local Law 39-2015

Source Doc: https://www.nyc.gov/assets/buildings/pdf/ll39of2011_electrical_code.pdf

Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Q0_G3VITpx0iCULtANMHqydAv0ZmvcF/view?usp=share_link

Effective Date: November 19, 2013 


**SCTOMJ**`

var c = "Official Name:"
var official_name = description.search(c); 
if(official_name != -1){
    official_name = description.substring(official_name + c.length, description.indexOf("\n", official_name)).trim();
}
console.log(official_name)
```